# PostgreSQL inheritance: get the record class name

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance, single-table-inheritance, information-schema

I have a base table *value_list* with columns *code*, *value*, *active*.
I have some tables *vl_a*, *vl_b*, *vl_c*, etc. inheriting from *value_list*.

Is there a way, when doing a `SELECT * FROM base` to know from which class the child comes from.

In other words, I would like to have:

```
code | value |  active | class
-----+-------+---------+--------
 1   |   c   |  true   | vl_a
 3   |   g   |  false  | vl_b
 5   |   d   |  true   | vl_a
 7   |   f   |  false  | vl_c
 2   |   u   |  false  | vl_c
 2   |   q   |  true   | vl_b
 8   |   a   |  false  | vl_a
```

Is this possible ?

For more details, here would be the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE value_list(
  code integer NOT NULL,
  value character varying(50),
  active boolean,
  CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY (code)
)

CREATE TABLE vl_a() INHERITS (value_list);
CREATE TABLE vl_b() INHERITS (value_list);
CREATE TABLE vl_c() INHERITS (value_list);
```

Comment: Could you maybe add your database schema with table definitions to the question. It's not all clear how they're designed.

Comment: here you go, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution on the [Postgres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-inherit.html).

```
SELECT p.relname, vl.* 
FROM qgep.is_value_list_base vl, pg_class p 
WHERE vl.tableoid = p.oid;
```

Answer (score 1):

dictionary won't let you to, but you can union manually:

```
   select *,'vl_a' from vl_a
    union all
    select *,'vl_b' from vl_b
    union all
    select *,'vl_c' from vl_c
```

[image]

well, this gives it:

```
create or replace function uall() returns table ( code integer ,
  value character varying(50),
  active boolean,tablename text ) AS $$ 
declare
  _i int;
  _r record;
  _t text := '';
begin 
  select distinct string_agg($s$select *,'$s$||table_name||$s$' from $s$||table_name,' union all ') into _t from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'vl_%';
return query execute _t;
end;$$ language plpgsql
;

select * from uall()
```

Comment: I have about 100 tables...I wanted to do this programmatically. Maybe using information_schema.

Comment: well you can create a function which returns setof or table or query and use execute dynamic sql for that...

Comment: @DenisRouzaud I updated to be dynamic from info schema

Comment: thanks for your help! I wanted to avoid using execute. The generated query is awfully long. There were a second page for inheritance on the postgres doc, and they give the solution in it.